# Sending a list of values of the same field to MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with ID as a primary key and other for this matter non-important fields.
What I would like to do is delete multiple records by sending a list of IDs for deletion as a parameter to stored procedure.

I know how to do this manually (building a query directly in PHP) but I would like to avoid that and do all my SQL directly in the DB.

Tried searching SO but couldn't find any related questions. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave +1 to @Marc B for clever use of FIND_IN_SET().  It won't be able to use an index, so the performance won't be good, but it should work.

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817) that can work (but will be slow as well, because it can't use an index):

```
DELETE FROM sometable 
WHERE CONCAT(',', param, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', idfield, ',%')
```

The solution that @Andrej L describes isn't really parameter binding, it's *interpolation* of a stored procedure argument into a dynamic SQL string prior to [preparing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) it.

```
SET sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM sometable WHERE idfield IN (', param, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

You can't parameterize a list of values with a single parameter, even if the parameter's value looks like a comma-separated list of integers.

Interpolation can work, and it *will* benefit from an index, but be careful to filter the string so it contains *only* numeric digits and commas.  Otherwise you introduce a significant risk of SQL injection (debunking the claim that some people make that stored procedures are inherently more secure).

Comment: Thanks a lot, accepted this response because of additional information.

Answer (score 3):

In accordance to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-B-4-1-17 you can't do it directly.

But I think you can try to the following trick:

1. Create string of you ids in php like 'id1,id2,id3'.
2. Use prepared statement for binding this sting on fly.

Maybe it helps.

Comment: No problem. Bill expanded my idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idfield, @param)
```

no idea if this'd work (and don't have access to a mysql instance right now to test on). Basically the problem is that if you pass in a comma-separated value list into a paramter, it'll just be a string inside the sproc, and doing a `WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')` would fail, since that's just a simple string and not at all the same as `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`. The [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function should take care of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I'm not proficient in MySQL so didn't know what to search for exactly. I remember the hassle I had with Oracle and casting comma delimited strings to specific types and then using them in a query to achieve this result. :)